# Different Stack Pointer at the same point for multiple runs

Tags: linux, exploit

I am encountering the following behavior for multiple runs of a program on a Linux x86 machine:

- the command run is `env -i ./prog`. The program is crafted to fail with a SIGSEGV
- the output from dmesg shows that the Stack Pointer at the time of the SIGSEGV varies after each execution, even though the program's flow is exactly the same

I have disabled the ASLR.

Why is the SP varying after each execution?

Comment: How did you disable ASLR ?
Is there any additional gcc option you should use when you compile prog  (such as  `-fno-stack-protector`) ?

Comment: Yes, the -fno-stack-protector is used. I disabled the ASLR with the setarch -R command for bash. Strangely, on another machine, the stack pointer stays the same over multiple calls.

Comment: Did you try to write directly in  /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space to set its value to 0 ( `sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` ) ? because when I try with the `setarch` command, this value doesn't change in this file, I don't know if it's normal or not...